# JS addEventListener arguments

Tags: javascript, function, events, parameter-passing, addeventlistener

I have an HTML page with several forms (created dynamically), so I get them in JS into an array, and then I add an `EventListener` to each one, like this:

```
var forms = document.getElementsByTagName('form');

for(i=0; i < forms.length; i++) {
    forms[i].addEventListener('change', function(){
        checkAllFilled(i);
    });
}
```

So in function `checkAllFilled` I do some stuff.

The problem is that if I have 7 forms (from `forms[0]` to `forms[6]`) and I work over `forms[2]`, it is always called `checkAllFilled(7)`, instead of calling `checkAllFilled(2)`. It's like the variable `i` was set in the last value over the for loop.

How would I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: What @Utkanos said + you need to have declare your `i` variable. (`var i = 0`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is just to use let from ECMAScript 2015.

```
for(let i=0; i < forms.length; i++) {
    forms[i].addEventListener('change', function(){
        checkAllFilled(i);
    });
}
```

Comment: That's a great solution! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> It's like the variable "i" was set in the last value over the for
>   loop.

This is exactly what's happening.

Think about it. Your event handler runs later, after the for-loop has been and gone. At that time, the variable has whatever value the loop left it with - hence, the event will always report the same, single value.

Instead, you need to bind the iterative value in via a closure. There's a few ways. One is via an immediately-executed function (IEF).

```
forms[i].addEventListener('change', (function(i) { return function(){
    checkAllFilled(i);
}; })(i));
```

We pass the iterative value to our IEF as a function variable. This way, it's passed to the handler via a closure. It's worth [reading up on these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).

Comment: Thanks for the explanaiton and reference :) But it doesn't work! :(

Comment: The IIF needs to take the passed argument and that is what needs to be used when invoking `checkAllFilled` instead of `i`. As this code example now reads, it doesn't do anything different from the original code.

Comment: Typo - missed `i` as the IEF argument. Resolved and works. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 1):

You are always calling the last generated event listener, since you generate first these listeners (all with same name) and then call the last one of them.

The best solution here is to assign names for the functions handling the events based on the counter value i.

Answer (score 1):

Use `forEach()`instead of a `for` loop:

```
var forms = document.getElementsByTagName('form');

[].slice.call(forms).forEach(function(form, i) {
    form.addEventListener('change', function(){
        checkAllFilled(i);
    });
});
```